# Tables and loops VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am new to coding and have written some code to do some calculations within a table and fill in columns. I have it working for the first row within the table but I am having some trouble figuring out how to loop it so that it completes the calculations for every row within the table. Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

Thanks for the Help! The code works perfectly for the first part provided here, I have tried to apply this to the other 2 parts, but am coming up with an error. I think due to the fact that I am trying to use a string as the input? I have tried without the quotation marks but all it returns is "#NAME?".

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1")

Dim formulaText As String
formulaText = 
"=IF([@Reach]>=100000,5,IF([@Reach]>=50000,3,IF([@Reach]>=10000,2,1)))"
tbl.ListColumns("Media Significance").DataBodyRange.Formula = formulaText


Dim formulaText1 As String
formulaText1 = "=IF([@Headline Mentions]>="Yes",5,IF([@Exclusive 
Mentions]>="Yes",3,1))"
tbl.ListColumns("Prominence Score").DataBodyRange.Formula = formulaText1


Dim formulaText2 As String
formulaText2 = "=IF([@Sentiment]>="Very Positive",2,IF([@Sentiment]>="Very 
Negative",2,1))"
tbl.ListColumns("Very Positive/ Very Negative").DataBodyRange.Formula = 
formulaText2


End Sub
```

Comment: Step through this with `F8`, and you'll be able to follow it line by line.  That should help you see where the logic isn't doing what you expect, and tweak from there.  Note, when you're on a line you can hover the mouse over a variable, and it'll have a nice little tool-tip type thing showing what that variable currently is.

Comment: You have a good start here. Here is some looping help: [http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html]  Try something out and let us know how it is working.

Comment: Typically, you would chose a start row and stop row for an important column and use that series of row numbers to access the cells in the other columns. Is there one column with values that is more important than the others or can any column with the values compared to above do as the lower limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through each cell in a range is very slow, so you're either going to want to either load your data into an array first, or use a regular Excel formula + the FillDown function.

In this particular case, I'd recommend the second option, which will allow you to add your formula to a single cell and fill it down the rest of the column. Something like this should work:

```
Dim colNum As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example Sheet")
    'Find last row in sheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Add first formula
    colNum = .Range("V2").Column
    .Cells(2, colNum).Formula = "=IF(T2>=100000,5,IF(T2>=50000,3,IF(T2>=10000,2,1)))"
    .Range(.Cells(2, colNum), .Cells(lastRow, colNum)).FillDown
End With
```

One problem with your current code is that the column letters are hard-coded. IE, you're expecting to find something called "Reach" in column L, and assuming that this will always be the case. However, if you ever add another column to the left of "Reach", it will break your code.

That's one reason why I'd probably recommend turning your range into a [table object](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-reasons-to-use-excels-table-object/) with descriptive column names. That should make your code much easier to read and maintain, like this:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example Sheet").ListObjects("YourTable")

Dim formulaText As String
formulaText = "=IF([@Reach]>=100000,5,IF([@Reach]>=50000,3,IF([@Reach]>=10000,2,1)))"
tbl.ListColumns("Reach Analysis").DataBodyRange.Formula = formulaText
```

Comment: A CommandButton1_Click sub procedure is typically on a worksheet's private code sheet. While it is important to provide a parent worksheet reference when dealing with cells in a public module code sheet, you can defer to the default parent worksheet in a worksheet's private code sheet without undue penalty.

Comment: If this macro were literally always going to be called from the command button-- or if it were definitely in the private code sheet-- sure, you could default to the ActiveSheet. But I have no idea if that's actually the case, so I didn't assume. Honestly, based on what the macro is actually doing, it'd be pretty strange to assign it to a button (or to make it a private sub at all). And since the OP seems relatively new to VBA, I'd rather not get them in the habit of using unqualified ranges.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help! If you could please have a look at my update I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Whenever your formula includes the " character, you need to add an additional one. So instead of "Yes" type ""Yes"".

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you have redundant criteria in your first If/ElseIf/End If statement.

This,

```
If Reach >= 100000 Then
    Result = 5
ElseIf Reach < 100000 And Reach >= 50000 Then
    Result = 3
ElseIf Reach < 50000 And Reach >= 10000 Then
    Result = 2
ElseIf Reach < 10000 Then
    Result = 1
End If
```

... can be written more succinctly as,

```
If Reach >= 100000 Then
    Result = 5
ElseIf Reach >= 50000 Then
    Result = 3
ElseIf Reach >= 10000 Then
    Result = 2
Else
    Result = 1
End If
```

These If/ElseIf/Else/End If conditions are resolved sequentially. Since you won't get into the second criteria unless *Reach* is less than 100000, there is no need to put that specification into the second criteria. The same logic can be applied for the remainder of the conditions.

Your second If/ElseIf/End If has an error in syntax.

```
ElseIf Headline = "No" And Exclusive = Yes Then
```

The **Yes** here should be quoted or the condition will be looking for a variable named *Yes*. Putting **Option Explicit** at the top of the module code sheet in the Declarations area will catch these errors quickly. You can also access the VBE's Tools, Options command and put a checkmark beside *Require Variable Declaration* and *Option Explicit* will be automatically put into the Declaration area of each new code sheet you create.